# Internet explorer 408 Result in Fiddler causes entire page to cancel all subsequent postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms, fiddler

I am trying to troubleshoot an issue that is only happening in Internet Explorer on a production server. In my Visual Studio dev environment everything works fine. On production in any browser but IE everything works fine.

It is happening during the page load of a specific page in my application. After the page load, all subsequent postbacks do not work. I get a 408 error in Fiddler.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20636749/http-status-408-error-with-tomcat-form-based-authentication) and it must be exactly what my problem is because as soon as I added the suggested meta tags to my master page everything works fine.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate"> 
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"> 
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
```

Can someone give me a brief explanation of why these meta tags are needed for my site to work? I feel like something I am doing with the AJAX might be incorrect or my production IIS settings might be wrong. Or is it just IE being IE?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of IE is installed, and are all patches installed?

Can you provide a network trace, or more information about the `HTTP/408` in question? If Fiddler is generating the `408` as I suspect it is, the problem is related to the fact that the client promised to submit a `POST` body but then didn't send any bytes.

Historically, there have been a number of bugs in IE near here related to the fact that, if IE expects to get an NTLM/Negotiate authentication challenge on a request, it will deliberately omit the POST body (in violation of standards) to save bandwidth. If the server fails to send an Authentication challenge, the client then fails to submit the body and the request times out. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/11/22/internet-explorer-post-bodies-are-zero-bytes-in-length-when-authentication-challenges-are-expected.aspx

In IE10, there were additional bugs in this area that have since been fixed in patches.

Comment: IE 11 and all patches are installed. You are exactly right about the client promising to submit a POST body but then didn't send any bytes. If I set the AjaxManager on the page to EnableAjax=false everything works. How can I get a Network Trace?

Comment: I really think the issue has to do with the Ajax request timing out since it is only happening when Ajax is enabled and when certain data is being selected from the database. For example if we select one filter it doesn't happen, if we select another filter it does happen. Very strange... http://cypressnorth.com/programming/internet-explorer-aborting-ajax-requests-fixed/

Comment: I thought maybe setting the AsyncPostBackTimeout="150000" to my asp:ScriptManager would fix it and it does not.

Comment: Sorry to keep adding information to this post. I think I finally found a solution, but still don't know if I fully understand. I am using the Telerik RadAjaxManager to manage all of the Ajax that is happening on my page. I was doing research and came across a property called: RequestQueueSize. If I have to take a random guess IE was counting some of my Ajax Requests as simultanous especially when database calls take longer. Let me know what you think. http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/ajax/how-to/ajax-requests-queueing

Answer (score 0):

As noted on the other question, this is down to session cookie handling by IE and IIS.

- IIS requires that in order for a cookie-based login to remain valid, it should receive some sort of contact from the client within a certain time. Typically this might be 30 minutes.
- If you tell IE that a resource at a URL is valid for an hour, or a day or forever, it may be more than 30 minutes before IE decides to re-check with the server to see if the page has changed. Instead it will used cached data.
- Therefore, if you don't put appropriate cache times on your resources, and the user only looks at pages they have seen before, IE might not get in touch with the server (since it has all the data cached).
- Therefore the login might timeout (408 error).

Probably the real underlying problem is you should set appropriate timeouts on your resources.

The headers/meta tags as given essentially turn off all caching - this is unnecessary and probably not what you want. If you are expecting the page to change every 5-10 minutes, you might want to put a cache timeout of 1 minute, for example. Instead consider how long IE should cache the resources for, and put that.

**TL;DR:** use proper cache-control headers.

Comment: I don't think my issue has to do with the session cookie created during login. I am instantly going to the page that is causing the problem right after logging in. I have spent days trying to figure out the problem. I believe the only cookie the site is storing is for the login, but no other page on the site has this problem. Production server is Windows Server 2008 R2, and only Internet Explorer completely crashes on SelectedIndexChange of any of the dropdowns with autopostback on the page. When I set RadAjaxManager Ajax=false the problem goes away, but no error.